# How to disable Swiping drawer to dismiss in react-native-navigation-drawer-extension

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using react-native-navigation and react-native-navigatioin-drawer-extension.

```
"react-native": "^0.62.2",
"react-native-navigation": "^7.0.0",
"react-native-navigation-drawer-extension": "^3.0.0",
```

I want to disable swiping drawer and I try to add swipeToDismiss: false to passProps and options objects. But I didn't get the result that I want and it didn't work. I want that because the drawer make lag and stop in screen when I swiping to dismiss. Please help me to solve this problem.

```
RNNDrawer.showDrawer({
  component: {
    name: Screens.Menu,
    passProps: {
      animationOpenTime: 300,
      animationCloseTime: 300,
      direction: 'right',
      dismissWhenTouchOutside: true,
      fadeOpacity: 0.6,
      swipeToDismiss: false,
      parentComponentId: componentId ? componentId : Screens.Main,
    },
    options: {
      statusBar: statusBar,
    },
  },
  options: {
    swipeToDismiss: false,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just open an issue in [react-native-navigation-drawer extension](https://github.com/aspect-apps/react-native-navigation-drawer-extension/issues/62) repo and report this bug!
And contributors make commit and fix bugs in the latest version with adding 2 props `disableDragging` and `disableSwiping`
Please see [this reply](https://github.com/aspect-apps/react-native-navigation-drawer-extension/issues/62#issuecomment-916827145) to my issue!
Thanks to the contributor [CursedWizard](https://github.com/CursedWizard)